# Get part of a string using a RegEx in Dart

Tags: regex, string, dart

I have this sentence `commerce_product--default` which I want to extract only the last part so here `default`, to do so I'm using this RegEx `RegExp(r'-\s*\K[^-]+$')`

Now I try to display it in my code but I didn't find the method to do it, I've tried with stringMatch or replaceAll like this :

```dart
final type = 'commerce_product--default';
final newType = type.replaceAll(RegExp(r'-\s*\K[^-]+$'), type);
```

but it didn't work.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Why don't you replace before the last `-` with an empty string? `^.*-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace all before the last occurrence of `-` you could also match the whole line until the last occurrence  of it and assert that what follows
is 1+ times any char except `-` until the end of the string.

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^.*-\s*(?=[^-]+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKzkPq/1) | [Dart demo](https://tio.run/##NYxLCsIwFADXeoq3EF5STS8gRVx4AXGnVkLyKoEkDc/UD@LZY0XdDjNjNedSrr2zELSLQsJzOulc1B7yIxE0gKYPgdjQKXFvB5OVstTpwWdc/tVIt93X/kQ1U/La0Np7saXz5p4EY1tX6nCpxKrZt@o4n0mUC0CU4yOxi1n8HiN4lfIG)

```
final type = 'commerce_product--default';
final newType = type.replaceAll(RegExp(r'^.*-\s*(?=[^-]+$)'), '');
print(newType);
```

Output

```
default
```

Comment: thanks for your comment! indeed it does work exactly like the first answer but it uses a bit less of code so I would use it instead!

Comment: @StefanYYC It's worth noting that this application requires a somewhat complex RegExp pattern to match but is fairly trivial using non-RegExp means. (See Irn's answer)

Answer (score 2):

To match everything after the last `-`, you should just match all trailing non-`-` characters:

```dart
var lastPartRE = RegExp(r"[^-]*$");
var lastPart = lastPartRE.firstMatch()?.group(0);
```

This matches all trailing non-`-` characters.

If the string does not contain any `-`, then it just matches the entire string. If you want a non-match in that case, you can put in a requirement for the `?`:

```dart
var afterLatDashRE = RegExp(r"(?<=-)[^-]+$");
```

This would require a minus character before the match.

I'd probably just omit the RegExp entirely and do it with code:

```dart
String lastPart(String text) {
  return text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a PCRE pattern that is not supported in Dart regex. You may use

```
final type = 'commerce_product--default';
final newType = RegExp(r'-\s*([^-]+)$').firstMatch(type);
if (newType!=null) {
  print(newType.group(1));
}
```

It is basically the same (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zAhd4B/1)), but without [`\K` *match reset operator*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), and the part you need to extract is wrapped with capturing parentheses. These parentheses create a *group* (here, with ID = 1) that you may access (with `newType.group(1)`) after a match is found (`if (newType!=null)` check is thus important).

I suggest using `.firstMatch()` here since you expect a single match at the end of the string.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info! I haven't been working with Dart a lot yet and I didn't know that. Funny enough I've got the Regex from one of your reply too ahaha! Just tested and it works as expected, thank you!